# What is the usage of "such...as that"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Please read this sentence's example:

> Considering how many hundreds of statues of the great Emperor must
> exist in London, it is too much to suppose **such** a coincidence **as** **that**
> a promiscuous iconoclast should chance to begin upon three specimens
> of the same bust.

This is from *Sherlock Holmes — The Adventure of the Six Napoleons* . If "as" is a preposition, I think, the that-clause can not follow it.

Comment: There is something wrong, like a missing word, but hard to pinpoint what it is.

Comment: [Analyzed here on forum.wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/suppose-such-a-coincidence-as-that.4080258/).

Answer (score 2):

There must be a nominal after [such] [a coincidence, etc] [as].

> - Who knows if perhaps you were made queen for just such a time as this?”

[[Esther 4:14; NLT courtesy of BibleHub](https://biblehub.com/esther/4-14.htm)]

The nominal may be other than a simple phrase:

> - Still, if Charles *had* been suspected of treason, it seemed unlikely that the Party would have had the patience to wait for such a
>   coincidence as his son's being denounced. [emphasis mine]

[[The Children's War; J N Stroyar](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nqrWNwgbUkIC&pg=PA915&lpg=PA915&dq=%22such+a+coincidence+as+his%22&source=bl&ots=RekdgDgs53&sig=ACfU3U2XvE8HvSQh20xp1uq1IDcMR6zL4g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXpa7Nt8mEAxXbV0EAHaP2CFwQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22such%20a%20coincidence%20as%20his%22&f=false)]

> - ... such a coincidence as his possessing a weapon which it fitted must be prevented....

[[Edith Metcalfe; Pyramids of Snow](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/72428/pg72428-images.html)]

And a declarative content clause ('that-clause') is a nominal:

- He denied that he had done it. // He denied everything.

> - That both defendants were lying was obvious to everyone in the courtroom. [[Oskar Garstein, Rome and the Counter-Reformation in Scandinavia. E.J. Brill, 1992](https://www.thoughtco.com/that-clause-definition-1692539#:%7E:text=In%20English%20grammar%2C%20a%20%22%20that,appositive%20in%20a%20declarative%20sentence.)] // Their deceit was obvious to ....

Conan Doyle here uses the wordy that-clause

> - ... that a promiscuous iconoclast should chance to begin upon three specimens of the same bust.

Fairly unusual, but grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> such a great *striker* as  *Harry Kane*

striker <=> Harry Kane

A striker the likes of the great Harry Kane.

In your example

> such a *coincidence* as *that a promiscuous iconoclast should chance to begin upon three specimens of the same bust*

the equivalence is between the noun **coincidence** and the noun clause headed by **that**.

That a promiscuous iconoclast should chance to begin upon three specimens of the same bust = that a vandal should have chosen these three specimens at random.

The notion that this was random is too much to suppose.

*That this was random* is too much to suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It’s a ***such as*** construction (*a coincidence **such as***) that has been split (***such*** a coincidence **as**). It’s followed by a *that*-clause (noun clause):

> *Considering how many hundreds of statues of the great Emperor must exist in London, it is too much to suppose a coincidence **such as**
> that a promiscuous iconoclast should chance to begin upon three
> specimens of the same bust.*

<sub>See also: Grammarphobia: [Can “such as” be separated?](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2014/09/such-as.html)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

In the above sentence, "as" is a conjunction, not a preposition, used in the phrase "such a coincidence as that" to highlight the nature of a coincidence.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).